# Importing shapefiles into SQL Server using ogr2ogr

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, shapefile

I want to import a shp file into SQL Server 2012 and when I run the following command in a cmd prompt:

`ogr2ogr -f CSV output.csv myshape.shp -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT`

I get the following error:

```
'ogr2ogr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Should I have done something else ?

Comment: ogr2ogr is an external program, not part of SQL Server. It comes as part of GDAL and can be downloaded from http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries. You will also need to add it to your windows environment variable.

Comment: Specifically, the PATH environment variable, or specify the full path of the utility on the command line